# Question about trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry

I’m doing some trig questions from a book to brush up my trig knowledge. And I have come across two questions that I can’t seem to find solutions

First Question

> If $A$ and $B$ are acute angles, find $A+B$, given:
>
> (a) $\tan A = 1/4$, $\tan B = 3/5$. Hint: $\tan (A + B) = 1$
>
> (b) $\tan A =5/3$, $\tan B = 4$.

According to the above hint I know $A+B$ must be $45$ degrees. But other than that I don’t know how $\tan A= 1/4$, $\tan B=3/5$ come in to the picture. I would appreciate if anyone can help me understand how to solve this kind of problems.

Second question is

> Find the values of $\sin 2A$, $\cos 2A$, and $\tan 2A$, given that $\tan A = u$,  in quadrant one

I know how to find $\tan2A$ using identities and answer for that is 
$2u/(1-u^2)$

But for $\cos2A$ and $\sin2A$, I can’t get the answers given in the book,
The answers given in the book are
$$
\sin2A = \frac{2u}{1+u^2},\qquad
\cos2A = \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}
$$

Again highly appreciate if anyone can help me out on these.

Thank you

Comment: Use $\tan(x+y) = \frac{sin(x+y)}{cos(x+y)}$, and the sum of angles formula.

Comment: cud u mabe fiks yur speling punctuashin an capitalizashun? its reel destractin

Comment: There are nice solutions using complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

First use $\displaystyle \tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}$

We know if $\displaystyle \tan x=\tan \alpha$

The general value of $x$ is $n\pi+\alpha$ where $n$ is an integer

Here $\alpha=\frac\pi4$

Then use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) to find the principal value of $A+B$

For the second, use [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution)

Comment: And in the second one, OP is just supposed to manipulate the double agle formulas in a clever way.

Comment: @chubakueno,please find the edited version. Also, "quadrant one" in the second ques,  right?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For 1st question what i don't understand is how do you use tanA=1/4, tanB=3/5 to arrive at the answer for (a) and tanA = 5/3 and tanB=4 for (b). the answers given in the book are (a) 45 degrees (b) 135 degrees

Comment: Just put the values of $\tan A,\tan B$ in the formula I mentioned in the first line of the answer

Comment: okay i got the answer for the 1st one.

Comment: @user119020, nice to hear that. What about the second